# Discord.js embed say command

Tags: discord, discord.js, replit

I am trying to code a command so when someone says !embed    it sends an embed to their channel with the title, description and the color as they put in the message, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//the message must be like (!embed Title-<> Color-<> Description)
//!embed Title-<test one> Color-<#ffffff> test test test test test

let title = message.content.split("Title-<")[1].split(">")[0];
let color = message.content.split("Color-<")[1].split(">")[0];

let description = message.content
      .replace("!embed","")
      .replace(`Title-<${title}>`,"")
      .replace(`Color-<${color}>`,"")

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(title)
      .setDescription(description)
      .setColor(color)

message.channel.send(embed)
```

well, I am not good at English
but if the answer is not working , plz tell me to modify it
[it will work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3jU.png)